# MYSQL Best way to break huge data over time?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I'm currently designing a system that oversees some devices that i need to keep logs and data for them.
Data is going to be received and stored every 15 seconds from each device.
Now i've had some experience in designing database schema but not of this size before.

There will be 2 tables.
One with the device info and the other one with the stats.
Thing is that if we have 5.000 devices then we're talking close to 25 million results in a day. In a couple of weeks that table is going to get big enough.

Now most of the time i'll be needing to run queries concerning the past day
so i was thinking of somehow to break this all down into more tables.

Having one running all the time and updating that live and say at the end of each week move all the data to another one and keep them there in case i need to run some queries with the old data.

Now should i stick with InnoDB ? Only foreign key i would use is just for device id in the stats table.

Thank you

Comment: Try reading something about partitioning - creating partition per week/month lets you remove old data really fast and newest data can be processed much faster. And disk space is reclaimed directly after removing parition. But there are some downsides (indexes are "local" per partition, you cannot have non-partitioning unique key - which probably won't matter in your case). If you need to store old data long time, you can use some ways of archiving them to separate table/database/server and then use fast removing to keep "operational" table small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generally only want to look at data in the past day, then my suggestion is to partition the data by day.  You can learn more about MySQL partitioning [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).

Depending on the queries, you will also want indexes on the date and device.  With 28.8 million rows per day, many queries should finish in a reasonable time.

One nice aspect of partitions is that they can be dropped and archived with minimal impact on the performance of the database.

By the way, 5,000 inserts every 15 seconds is 333 inserts/second.  You will want to be sure that your hardware is sufficient for this volume of transactions.